# How do I use bigdump.php with Acquia Dev Desktop?

Tags: database, importing-exporting

I am trying to import a rather large database (~450MB) on my local machine (running [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop)). To do this, I was going to use [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/).

However, I must not be configuring bigdump.php correctly because I keep getting this error:

> Database connection failed due to No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Here's my database configuration in bigdump.php.

```
$db_server   = 'localhost';
$db_name     = 'testdb';
$db_username = 'drupaluser';
$db_password = '';
```

Do I have to edit something in Acquia Dev Desktop to allow connections?

Comment: Doesn't Acquia use 33066 for the MySQL port by default? That might be all you need to change...

Comment: @Clive Yes, port 33066. I don't see a place to specify that in bigdump.php. Would I have to change the MySQL port in Acquia? To which port?

Comment: 'Fraid I've never used bigdump so I couldn't tell you what their default for the MySQL port is. I imagine there will be instructions on their website somewhere though

Comment: But if they've written their code with any semblance of order than it should surely be a matter of adding `$db_port = '33066';` (default for MySQL is 3306 BTW)

Comment: @Clive I've tried adding `$db_port = '33066;` with no luck, but I may have done it wrong (still new to this). I will try it again. Thanks!

Comment: Posting this as a comment because it doesn't address your question, but you will have better luck using MySQL Workbench, Navicat, or similar tool.  The mysql command line interface will also be a good option.  Just remember to read up on max_allowed_packet no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a web based solution for moving in database files, you should be using the Drupal solution for it:

http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

*Backup and Migrate simplifies the task of backing up and restoring your Drupal database or copying your database from one Drupal site to another. It supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.*

*With Backup and Migrate you can dump some or all of your database tables to a file download or save to a file on the server, and to restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. You can chose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is excluded by default.*

Comment: bigdump.php also is not particularly required as Acquia Dev Desktop has its own interface for importing files. :) (I used to work for Acquia)

Comment: I was under the impression that that module wasn't the best option for large databases like this one (~450MB). But I will certainly give it a try. Also, I got the initial import with Acquia Dev Desktop, but didn't see a way to import new databases offhand. I will have to look again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer is certainly an acceptable solution for some... for anyone looking for the answer to the actual original question (like I was):

You enter the port on the $db_server line.

```
$db_server   = 'localhost:port';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specifying `$db_server = 'localhost:port';` didn't work for me (BigDump v0.36b). To connect to the DB, BigDump uses `new mysqli(...)` that accepts port as a separate parameter. Thus, all what you need is to edit your `bigdump.php` a bit:

1) Add `$db_port` variable at line 42:

```
$db_port = '33066';
```

2) Use it at line 395:

```
{ $mysqli = new mysqli($db_server, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name, $db_port);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the game here, but why can't you use the mysql prompt (type `mysql` in terminal) to connect to the database, and use mysqldump to import the db file?

See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24372/10994